# Spring scope for multi-threading

Tags: spring

I am working on a web applicatoin using Spring for it.
I have created a service componenet and sssign scope "prototype" to it.
But when I am going to access a page which has internally call the methods of service class refering the same instance becuase of that it changed the data.
"prototype" itself create a new object in whenever we call for for new object then why it is not creating the new object and refering the same. Any idea?

Thanks,
Atul

Comment: it is too hard understand the correct mean of your question. Please update your question with some snippets of code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to fact that when you debugging, your prototype instance is actually same object in debugger. It is because Spring is using proxy mechanism to create new objects. So what you see is the same proxy object instance. But prototype bean is always new.

If you put breakpoint into prototype bean (not to the caller) and inspect "this", you would realize that it's new object all the time.